# Distributing PyTorch model across GPUs

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have access to a computer with [4 Nvidia A10's](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-instances-g5-with-nvidia-a10g-tensor-core-gpus/). I would like to load a [model](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/instructblip) too large to fit on a single GPU for inference. This has to be possible, right? Most resources I've found relate to either [distributed training](https://github.com/pytorch/PiPPy/blob/inference_examples/README.md) or [multiple inferences](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/inference-on-multi-gpu/152419), not distributing the actual model. I've tried several different options like [Deep Speed](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/deepspeed#installation) and [DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dist_overview.html) but they all end up loading the model to a single GPU which causes out of memory. The closest I've gotten is using [Accelerate](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/en/usage_guides/distributed_inference#distributed-inference-with-accelerate) but I get an error stating that pytorch expects all tensors to be on a single GPU. Am I crazy?

Please forgive the fact that I'm not posting the actual error. If it is truly needed I will have to reproduce. Hoping there is an easier way...

Comment: You probably want fully sharded data parallel

Comment: Thanks. I’ll check it out. I guess part of my question is shouldn’t it be easier to deploy these? I mean with as many downloads as these models get I feel like I’m just missing something that everyone else knows about. Does everyone just run inference on cpu? If so why is there so much talk comparing what multi gpu set up is better?